# How can I get a value from 1 of several rows when one column that has the maximum value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are 3 tables as follows:

TEMPTable: contains all the values for a staff members

| Company | EmplNo | Seq | Status | Title | Level | TDESC | EntryDate | LevelDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 500 | 324778 | 1 | B | 3111A | M2 | Sr. Manager | 2002-10-07 | 2011-07-17 |
| 500 | 324778 | 1 | B | 3111A | M3 | Sr. Manager | 2002-10-07 | 2019-01-20 |
| 500 | 324778 | 1 | B | 3111A | M4 | Sr. Manager | 2002-10-07 | 2021-10-24 |
| 900 | 324778 | 1 | B | 31117 | M2 | Manager | 2002-10-07 | 2002-10-06 |
| 500 | 324778 | 1 | B | 31117 | M3 | Manager | 2002-10-07 | 2002-10-06 |
| 500 | 324778 | 1 | B | 31117 | M4 | Manager | 2002-10-07 | 2009-01-01 |

CurrentTable: contains the current information of each staff

| Company | EmplNo | Seq | Status | Title | Level | EntryDate | Grade | FName | Lname | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 500 | 324778 | 1 | B | 3111A | 00 | 07-OCT-2002 | 4 | James | Dohn | 47826.00 |

The result should be as shown below, with the MAX Level, the TDESC from the record with the MAX Level, and the MIN LevelDate:

DatesTable:

| Company | EmplNo | Status | Title | Level | TDESC | EntryDate | LevelDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 900 | 324778 | B | 3111A | 04 | Sr. Manager | 2002-10-07 | 2002-10-06 |

First I inserted the Company, EmplNo, Status, Title, Level, EntryDate dates table by using the SQL script below:

```
INSERT INTO DatesTable (Company, EmplNo, Status, Title, 
  CASE WHEN GRADE > 0 THEN LEFT(Level,1)+RIGHT(GRADE,1) ELSE Level END AS Level, EntryDate)
    (SELECT 
         C.Company, C.EmplNo, C.Status, C.Title, C.Level, C.EntryDate, 
         CONVERT(DATETIME, C.EntryDate, 112) 
     FROM 
         CurrentTable C 
     INNER JOIN 
         TEMPTable P ON C.EmplNo = P.EmplNo 
     WHERE 
         C.Company = P.Company
         AND C.Seq = P.Seq
         AND C.Status = P.Status
         AND C.Title = P.Title  
         AND CONVERT(DATETIME, C.EntryDate, 112) = P.EntryDate
         AND C.EmplNo = 324778  
     GROUP BY 
         Company, EmplNo, Status, Title, Level, EntryDate)
```

As mentioned, I need to get the maximum Level value, but I also need to obtain the TDESC that matches that Level.

I updated the LevelDate by using a previous SQL script I got before, which I included below:

```
UPDATE D
SET [LevelDate]= (SELECT MIN(T.LevelDate) as LevelDate 
                  FROM [TempTable] T 
                  WHERE T.Company = D.Company
                    AND T.EmplNo = D.EmplNo 
                    AND T.Status = D.Status
                    AND LEFT(T.Title, 4) = LEFT(D.Title, 4))
FROM [DatesTable] D
WHERE EmplNo = 324778
```

I needed to match on the first 4 positions of Title, because the title codes changed overtime, but it is the same title, and this match allows me to obtain the minimum LevelDate from the group of records for this staff.

What I can't figure out, is how to obtain the TDESC for the record that has the maximum Level or M4.

Can you help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[`Row_number`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) can  be used to get values that accompany a maximum or minimum.  Identify the maximum row with `row_number` and the appropriate `PARTITION` and `ORDER BY` in a CTE, then filter to that row in the main query.

If we start with your `TEMPTable`:

| EmplNo | Level | TDESC | LevelDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 324778 | M2 | Sr. Manager | 2011-07-17 |
| 324778 | M3 | Sr. Manager | 2019-01-20 |
| 324778 | M4 | Sr. Manager | 2021-10-24 |
| 324778 | M2 | Manager | 2002-10-06 |
| 324778 | M3 | Manager | 2002-10-06 |
| 324778 | M4 | Manager | 2009-01-01 |

Applying `row_number` assigns whatever ordering we want:

```sql
SELECT *,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY EmplNo ORDER BY Level DESC) as is_max
FROM TEMPTable
```

| EmplNo | Level | TDESC | LevelDate | is_max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 324778 | M4 | Sr. Manager | 2021-10-24 | 1 |
| 324778 | M4 | Manager | 2009-01-01 | 2 |
| 324778 | M3 | Sr. Manager | 2019-01-20 | 3 |
| 324778 | M3 | Manager | 2002-10-06 | 4 |
| 324778 | M2 | Manager | 2002-10-06 | 5 |
| 324778 | M2 | Sr. Manager | 2011-07-17 | 6 |

Then we filter to the row we want with a CTE.

```sql
    WITH cte_name as (
      SELECT *,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY EmplNo ORDER BY Level DESC) as is_max
      FROM TEMPTable
    )
    SELECT 
      *
    FROM 
       cte_name
    WHERE is_max = 1
```

Which gives us:

| EmplNo | Level | TDESC | LevelDate | is_max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 324778 | M4 | Sr. Manager | 2021-10-24 | 1 |

Bring the whole thing together to give the TDESC for the row with the max level is:

```sql
    WITH levels as (
      SELECT *,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY EmplNo ORDER BY Level DESC) as is_max
      FROM TEMPTable
    )
    SELECT 
      C.Company, C.EmplNo, C.Status, C.Title, P.Level, P.TDesc, C.EntryDate
    FROM 
      CurrentTable C 
      INNER JOIN levels P ON C.EmplNo = P.EmplNo
    WHERE is_max = 1
```

---

**Note:** this particular example is non-deterministic!  If you run this many time some will return the 2021-10-14 row as 1 and others the 2009-01-01 row.  If you were to actually use this you need to add columns to the `ORDER BY` until results are deterministic or use a `DISTINCT` first

Comment: I appreciate your response.  Howver, can you please explain the query more in detail?  What is Levels, is it an optional key word?  Why do we need to make Level descending?  Are we getting all the values here instead of from different queries which I did?  Remember I wanted the minimum LevelDate from the group of records when the 1st 4 position of Title matches, and the TDESC from the record with the maximum Level value.

Comment: To get the correct group of records relating to the CurrentTable, I need to match on Company, EmplNo, Status, Title, Level, & EntryDate.  Also, to get the minimum LevelDate for the title, I need to match on Company, EmplNo, Status, & first 4 position of TITLE.

Comment: Just so you know, I tried to run the query as is, but got an error message indicating that  levels.Level, levels.TDesc could not be bound.   Please assist.

Comment: @Sast77 `levels` is just a name for the Common Table Expression.  The query did not run due to the `P` alias, I've correct that now.

Comment: I appreciate your response.  The query ran after I made that update.  But I am still not sure what you were trying to achieve with this query, and it's also my lack of knowledge what the "WITH" clause does.  If you could explain it a little clearer I would appreciate it.    However, I may have to take 2 paths:  1) to match the 1st 4 positions of TITLE when the 5th position is alpha to process managers differently as shown in my UPDATE SQL, and all 5 positions for non-managers.  How can I do this in the where clause?